# Замена имен в текстовом файле DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

**Как решить задачу:** В текстовом файле, заменить все **имена файлов** на список имен из Memo. 
В Memo ввожу список имен (И программа, изменяет все имена в **текстовом файле**, между последним знаком **"/"** и точкой **"."**) на новые имена:

Comment: И в чем вопрос? Что у вас не получается сделать?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Все, что у меня получилось, это только обрезать пути, но это не то и к сожалению, дальше, не могу представить себе - как это реализовать.

Comment: А дальше добавить имя файла

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Обновила тему, там моя наработка, но дальше продвижения, у меня, нет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Readln(F1, S);
S := ExtractFilePath(S) + Memo1.Lines[Idx] + ExtractFileExt(S);
Writeln(F1, S);
Inc(Idx)
```

Comment: Но в таком случае идет изменение всех файлов с одним именем, а нужно по списку. То есть: первая строка файла, изменяет имя, на -первую строку memo и так далее.

Comment: Так индекс меняйте в цикле